# Trying to show property of fractional part

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, approximation

We have this sequence

$$\left\{\{\sqrt n\}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\;,\;\;\{\sqrt n\}:=\;\text{the fractional part of}\;\;\sqrt n$$

The exercise is to prove it doesn't have a limit, and we get several hints:

(1) Show zero is a partial limit .- this is easy as the subsequence $\;\left\{\{\sqrt{n^2}\}\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\;$ is identical with zero

(2) Prove that for any $\;M\in\Bbb N\;$ there exists $\;n>M\;$ such that $\;\{\sqrt n\}\ge\frac12\;$ .

This is the REAL problem: it's easy to show that $\;a_{N^2+1}=\left\{\sqrt{N^2+1}\right\}>0\;$ . Then the following misterious, for me, hint is given: if $\;a_{N^2+1}\ge\frac12\;$ then choose $\;n=N^2+1\;$ and we're done (this is clear to me), otherwise $\;0<a_{N^2+1}<\frac12\;$ . Show there exists $\;k\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. $\;a_{k^2(N^2+1)}\ge\frac12\;$ . Now

$$\;a_{k^2(N^2+1)}=\left\{\sqrt{k^2(N^2+1)}\right\}=\left\{k\sqrt{N^2+1}\right\}$$

This seems to hint towards taking integer multiples of $\;\sqrt{N^2+1}\;$ , and this seem very close to Dirichlet's Approximation theorem (with the pigeohole principle), yet I can't see how to show directly what's been asked without relying on Dirichlet's theorem, which is forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

Just consider $a_{M^2+M+1}$. Since $M^2+M+1<(M+1)^2$, we just have to prove:
$$\sqrt{M^2+M+1}-M\geq\frac{1}{2},$$
that is equivalent to:
$$M^2+M+1\geq \left(M+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2,$$
that is equivalent to:
$$ 1\geq \frac{1}{4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I would just look at $(N+1)^2-1$.

The hint probably wants you to say that for $a\in\mathbb N$, $\{ab\} = \{a\{b\}\}$, and find a value of $k$ that will do the trick.

Comment: BTW, we also have $$\{(0.9)\cdot(1.9)\}=\{1.71\}=0.71\neq 0.81=\{0.81\}=\{0.9\cdot0.9\}=\{0.9\cdot\{1.9\}\}$$ which shows that $\;\{ab\}\neq\{a\{b\}\}\;$ , in general.

Comment: Oh, I got so carried away with using different names for the variables, that I forgot that $a$ has to be in $\mathbb{Z}$ (and $\mathbb N$ is sufficient in this case).